# How to convert an RPC/encoded style WSDL into document/literal

Tags: soap, wsdl

I need to generate a new WSDL file in the document/literal style based on an old RPC/encoded one.  I've viewed the other WSDL questions here - and read http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/. This suggests that the document/literal WSDL should have an additional  part - but my old RPC/encoded document has such a part (or more precisely ) as well. Does that mean that I only need to change the bindings and I am done?

Answer (score 6):

This technical article may help you:
[**Converting RPC/literal to Document/literal**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996466.aspx#rpc_literal_topic3)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP, you can use the Zend framework's Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover class. It has options to generate different WSDL styles and uses. See here: http://www.phpriot.com/manual/zf/zend.soap.autodiscovery.wsdlstyles and here: http://www.phpriot.com/articles/zend-soap/6

Answer (score 0):

Use [CWSDLGeneratorDocument.php](https://github.com/Taron133/CWSDLGeneratorDocument) for generate WSDL file in DOCUMENT/LITERAl style and use standart library JAX-WS in java 1.7.

It's simply.